# Mutation with list of strings as argument in Prisma + GraphQL

Tags: list, graphql, prisma, mutation, resolver

I am trying to make a mutation but I am getting an error with the arguments.

In **schema.graphql** I have the following:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  age: Int!
  height: Float!
  weight: Float!
  goals: [String!]!
  history: [Routine!]!
}

type Mutation {
  signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!, age: Int!, height: Float!, weight: Float!, goals: [String!]!): AuthPayload
}
```

In **schema.prisma**:

```
model User {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  email     String   @unique
  password  String
  age       Int
  weight    Float
  height    Float
  goals     String[]
  history   Routine[]
}
```

Then my mutation resolver is the following:

```
async function signup(parent, args, context, info) {
  // 1
  const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)

  // 2
  const user = await context.prisma.user.create({ data: { ...args, password } })

  // 3
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET)

  // 4
  return {
    token,
    user,
  }
}
```

But when I try the function on GraphQL Playground for example with:

```
mutation {
  signup(
    name: "Esteban"
    email: "esteban@gmail.com"
    password: "Password"
    age: 23
    height: 1.84
    weight: 70.0
    goals: ["WEIGHT_LOSS"]
  ) {
    token
    user {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "signup": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "\nInvalid `context.prisma.user.create()` invocation in\n/Users/estebankramer1/Documents/ITBA/pf-proyf/server/src/resolvers/Mutation.js:10:42\n\n   6 // 1\n   7 const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)\n   8 \n   9 // 2\n→ 10 const user = await context.prisma.user.create({\n       data: {\n         email: 'esteban@gmail.com',\n         password: '$2a$10$hL1sMErBEcg98hpk5kRNpef2isI5d/O66zfRom8sQyThIHue7ku2O',\n         name: 'Esteban',\n         age: 23,\n         height: 1.84,\n         weight: 70,\n         goals: [\n           'WEIGHT_LOSS'\n         ]\n       }\n     })\n\nUnknown arg `0` in data.goals.0 for type UserCreategoalsInput. Available args:\n\ntype UserCreategoalsInput {\n  set?: List<String>\n}\n\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "signup"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I cannot find examples of Mutations with lists of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to change the mutation to the following:

```
async function signup(parent, args, context, info) {
  // 1
  const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10)

  // 2
  const user = await context.prisma.user.create({ data: {
    ...args,
      goals: {
        set: args.goals
      },
      password
  } })

  // 3
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, APP_SECRET)

  // 4
  return {
    token,
    user,
  }
}
```

Basically use a set operation.
I have no idea why, the documentation of Prisma is terrible. Maybe someone can clear things a bit?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. We are constantly working on improving the docs and you can find working with scalar lists [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/crud#working-with-scalar-lists--scalar-arrays). Also you can use `ctrl+space` to check for intellisense to view all the methods and properties that Prisma Client provides.